# MySql: Inserting python lists into a table

Tags: python, sql, database, mysql-connector

How do I insert these 2 lists into different SQL columns of the same table

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

This is the way to insert one list into a column

```
query = "INSERT INTO tableName (col1) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.executemany(query, [(r,) for r in a])
```

I can't seem to figure out how to insert both the lists into the table, I want list a to be in one column and list b to be in other column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = "INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2) values (%s, %s)"
cursor.executemany(query, [(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO sometable (somecol, somecol2) values (something, something)"
cursor.executemany(query, [(v, x) for v, x in zip(t, h)])
```